# Making a View Controller Scrollable in Easiest Way

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, bounce

The picture below is how my home screen looks. I have three elements: serach bar and two buttons. I want to make it so that the entire screen is vertically draggable so that it bounces a bit up and down. Is there an easy way to do this? I've heard scrollviews are a good way, but I'm not entirely sure where to start with scroll views here, for this specific case.

[image]

Comment: why don't take a tableViewController with search bar?

Comment: use UITableViewController or UICollectionViewController.

Comment: another simple way is to use CollectionView to display data

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder or is the whole thing setup in code? Table and Collection views, while both good choices, will require a little more work than plain `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Yea i thought of using a table view, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, considering I would have to change elements on storyboard significantly. I am using Interface builder.

Comment: Do you want the buttons to stay on the same place or  they should move too?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, though bear in mind that using scroll views in IB may be tricky, at least at first. So what you want is basically a layout like this :

```
                 (ScrollView)
+-------------------------------------------+
| +---------------------------------------+ |
| |                                       | |
| |               (TopView)               | |
| |                                       | |
| +---------------------------------------+ |
| +---------------------------------------+ |
| |                                       | |
| |            (BottomView)               | |
| |                                       | |
| +---------------------------------------+ |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Now the required constraints for this to work with autolayout are:

- ScrollView to Superview : pin all edges with desired margins
- TopView to ScrollView : pin top and side egdes
- BottomView to ScrollView : pin bottom and side edges
- TopView to BottomView : pin TopView bottom to BottomView top

And now for the more tricky ones :

- TopView to ScrollView : make widths equal
- BottomView to ScrollView : make width equal
- TopView to ScrollView : make heights equal and then change to proportional, i.e. 1:2
- BottomView to TopView : make heights equal

Then set `Bounces` and `Bounce Vertically` to `YES` (either in code or in IB), and everything should work.

The second set of constraints is what gives the scroll view basis for its `contentSize` calculations. They could actually be omitted if

- all of child views had a height constraint set to a constant number

or

- all of child views could derive their height from their content through other constraints